# Script which removes itself after the first execution

Tags: linux, shell

I want to develop a shell script that remove itself at the end of the execution.

How can this be done?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What did you try, and why do you want to do that?

Comment: I once had one, but I seem to have lost it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `[[ -f "$0" ]] && rm "$0"`. Might want to protect from write failures and otherwise.

Comment: It might not work if the script is in some directory of the `$PATH` which is not the current directory. Perhaps using `$(which $0)` might be better than just `$0` ...

Comment: That will similarly fail in the opposite case. I wouldn't use shell script for this at all.